# Multiple types of possible JSON files as return of HTTP request with spring

Tags: android, json, spring, jackson

I am using Spring for Android as an HTTP client. Say i do a request with basic authentication like this:

```
    // Create a new RestTemplate instance
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());


            try {
                // Make the network request
                Log.d(TAG, url);
                ResponseEntity<Message> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders), Message.class);
                System.out.println(response.toString());
            } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
```

What i understand is that a Message class should be a mapping of the JSON that i expect from to get back from this request. 
But now i have a problem: depending on the headers of the request, different types of JSON can return. If the user is authorized it gets:

```
{

    "message": "ok",
    "code": 200,
    "data:{
... just some more json data ..
           }
}
```

but when the user is not autorized, the data is missing (off course). So it would look like this

```
 {

    "message": "You are not authorized to use this service",
    "code": 5201

}
```

But this are two types of JSON files, how can i create a correct mapping (Message class) for both of these files? Or should i create different types of Messages classes?

I am afraid there is a pretty straightforward answer to this question, but could not find it myself. I hope someone can explain this to me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both json are same, the only difference is in second json data will be null,